# Ho to create single tableview for two UISegment Control with two different selection check mark using Swift?

Tags: swift

I am maintaining `UISegmentControl` and Search with a single tableview. Here, I am loading the tableview data from a JSON (language list).

Now I have two segment buttons like Source language and Target language and both segments tableviews also have same data. Here, whenever user selects source language a particular row is check marked and if then user clicks target language segment, the same check mark shows. I need to maintain separate data selections, also, I am going to use search bar.

Can you please provide me a solution for two different segment controller buttons but maintaining a single tableview and its data and UI look the same. Checkmark selection should be different and persistent.

[image]

My Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "languagecell", for: indexPath) as! LangCustomCell

    let item = langData[indexPath.row]

    cell.flag_img.sd_setImage(with:url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "usa.png"))
    cell.language_label.text = item.languageName
    cell.language_label.textColor = UIColor.gray
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    //configure you cell here.
    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the languages grouped with the first letter of the language? Or show all languages in one section?

Comment: only one section I am maintaining also data I am loading from JSON. Here target and source two segment button I am maintaining. user select cell check mark I am making but for two buttons two different check mark I need to persist for(eg: segment one user selected English and segment two Hindi .@RajeshKumarR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate variables to store selected languages for from and to.
In `tableView didSelectRowAt` method check save in appropriate variable based on the `selectedSegmentIndex`. In `TableView cellForRowAt` check the selected languages with current language. If `selectedSegmentIndex` and selected language matches use `.checkmark` else use `.none`

And create two arrays with type `[Language]`. In `searchBar textDidChange` method filter the languages array and reload the `tableView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    struct Language: Equatable {
        var title: String
        var icon: UIImage?
    }
    var allLanguages = [Language]()
    var filteredLanguages = [Language]()
    var selectedFromLanguage:Language?
    var selectedToLanguage:Language?

    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        allLanguages = [Language(title: "English", icon: UIImage(named:"uk"))]
        filteredLanguages = allLanguages
//      add constraints segmentedControl, tableView, searchBar in view
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredLanguages.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row].title
        cell.imageView?.image = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row].icon
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && selectedFromLanguage == filteredLanguages[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && selectedToLanguage == filteredLanguages[indexPath.row] {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return cell
    }
    // MARK: - Table view Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {//from
            selectedFromLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]
        } else {//to
            selectedToLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    // MARK: - Search bar Delegate
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredLanguages = allLanguages
        } else {
            filteredLanguages = allLanguages.filter({ $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) })
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

---

Use computed properties like this to persist the selected languages

```
var selectedFromLanguage:Language? {
    get {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "fromLanguage") as? Data,
            let language = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Language.self, from: data) {
            return language
        }
        return nil 
    }
    set {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "fromLanguage")
        }
    }
}
var selectedToLanguage:Language? {
    get {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "toLanguage") as? Data,
            let language = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Language.self, from: data) {
            return language
        }
        return nil
    }
    set {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "toLanguage")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setup an action for your `UISegmentControl`:

```
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        // do what you need with your tableView
    case 1:
        // do what you need with your tableView
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

when the index change setup your `tableView` and reload your data

Comment: @Alaster Can you please provide me some more info.

Comment: What @Alaster provided you is the right direction. Check a tutorial on how to use segmented controls: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/how-to-use-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios

Then just `tableView.reloadData` if needed and have two data sources that synchronize with each other when actions are done (search, checkmarks, selection, etc.)

Comment: @jackios show your numberofrowinsection and I can try to provide more info, but I don't really know all your code

Comment: @Alastar almost 200 row I am adding. the data I am getting from JSON.

Comment: I don't know your code it's almost impossibile to help you like this. the answer above is a good hint, can't you setup the datasource of tableview now?